# javascipt:Need to smooth the the lines drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, html5-canvas

so i have been trying to work on a canvas sketching app. and i had this problem where the line drawn are very unclean. As you can see from image below.

[image: untidy]

then i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062999/smooth-canvas-drawing-without-redrawing-everything/14063110#14063110) and got the below result which is what i desire.

[image: tidy]

But this created a new problem, the eraser function wont work. Now I've been trying to make this two work for sometime, but just could'nt do it.

So what i want is a new smoothing technique or a way to make the above two work.

BTW here is the demo without smoothing: http://jsbin.com/axarun/1/edit

and here is the demo with smoothing: http://jsbin.com/aviluk/2/edit

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1:

You can "force" the canvas to use anti-aliasing by doing this:

```
ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
```

Force in quotes as this is dependent on actual implementation in the browser you're using. Currently there is no way to enable/disable anti-alias by intention.

### Method 2:

Set the canvas to "high-resolution" by setting the canvas itself to double size, but force it to be displayed in the original size by styling the canvas element with CSS rules:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600" height="1200"
    style="width:800px;height:600px" />
```

Just remember to double your mouse-coordinates as well as pen-width. This will eat 4x more memory and performance, but will give you high-resolution lines (in appearance).

In this case the browser will treat the canvas as an image and apply anti-aliasing as it does for any scaled image, and not the canvas' method for anti-alias.

Please note that this is *not* the same as applying scale transform to the canvas.

See demo of "hi-res canvas" here:
http://jsfiddle.net/q2t5A/

### Method 3-ish:

For actual smooth lines you can check out my function to do so here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/562175/Draw-Smooth-Lines-on-HTML5-Canvas

This takes an array of x/y couples and smooths the line (cardinal spline). The lines will go through the original points and no control points are needed.

This will of course imply that you record the actual points, and when mouse up you redraw the canvas using the curve() function in this code. That would be a correct approach in any case, to record the strokes in an array and then redraw (this will also allow you to use layers). There are workarounds to avoid render *everything* by using off-screen
canvases to store f.ex. each layer. By drawing a canvas onto another with a small non-integer offset will force anti-alias (but see point 1).