# How to detect if mouse position is hovering

Tags: jquery

I have this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122553/create-a-realistic-pencil-tool-for-a-painting-app-with-html5-canvas) which indicates how to make a pencil tool.

How can I detect whether the mouse is hovering on drawn area/points/images using the pencil tool? Then it will highlight the starting point and the end point by creating a circle on it.

Comment: *Note:* Please do not delete and repost the same question if you did not happen to get an answer wanted the first time.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Noted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution in your case is to save all drawn points into arrays, themselves saved in one array containing all your pathes :

- `onmousedown` : create a new path array.
- `onmousemove`:
  -- if drawing -> fill the currentPath's array with every drawn points.
  -- else -> check if the actual mouse coordinates are in any of your path arrays.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  painting = false,
  lineThickness = 1;

canvas.width = canvas.height = 600;

var dCanvas = canvas.cloneNode(true);
dCtx = dCanvas.getContext('2d');
pCanvas = canvas.cloneNode(true);
pCtx = pCanvas.getContext('2d');
dCtx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
pCtx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);

var pathes = [],
  currentPath;

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
  currentPath = [];
  pathes.push(currentPath);
  painting = true;
};

canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
  painting = false;
}

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  pCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
    mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  if (painting) {   
    var lastPoint = currentPath[currentPath.length-1] || {
      x: e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
      y: e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop
    };
    var x1 = mouseX,
      x2 = lastPoint.x,
      y1 = mouseY,
      y2 = lastPoint.y;


    var steep = (Math.abs(y2 - y1) > Math.abs(x2 - x1));
    if (steep) {
      var x = x1;
      x1 = y1;
      y1 = x;

      var y = y2;
      y2 = x2;
      x2 = y;
    }
    if (x1 > x2) {
      var x = x1;
      x1 = x2;
      x2 = x;

      var y = y1;
      y1 = y2;
      y2 = y;
    }

    var dx = x2 - x1,
      dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1),
      error = 0,
      de = dy / dx,
      yStep = -1,
      y = y1;

    if (y1 < y2) {
      yStep = 1;
    }

    lineThickness = 5-Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)) / 10;
    if (lineThickness < 1) {
      lineThickness = 1;
    }

    for (var x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
      if (steep) {
        dCtx.fillRect(y, x, lineThickness, lineThickness);
        currentPath.push({x: y,y: x});
      } else {
        dCtx.fillRect(x, y, lineThickness, lineThickness);
        currentPath.push({x: x,y: y});
      }

      error += de;
      if (error >= 0.5) {
        y += yStep;
        error -= 1.0;
      }
    }
    currentPath.push({x: mouseX,y: mouseY});
  } else {
    pathes.forEach(function(path) {
      if (path.some(function(point) {
        return isBetween(mouseX, point.x, 5) && isBetween(mouseY, point.y, 5)
      })) {
        pCtx.beginPath();
        pCtx.arc(path[0].x+2.5, path[0].y+2.5, 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
        pCtx.fill();

        pCtx.beginPath();
        pCtx.arc(path[path.length-1].x+2.5, path[path.length-1].y+2.5, 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
        pCtx.fill();
      }
    });
  }
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  ctx.drawImage(dCanvas, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(pCanvas, 0, 0);
}

function isBetween(x, y, z) {
  return (x >= y - z && x <= y + z);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the (per pixel) image data from a canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData. Then check if the mouse is hovering over a green pixel.

Comment: but how would I get the first point and the last point if I will get the per pizel?

Comment: @AJB You get the first point from the event object passed to mousedown, and the second point from the event object passed to mouseup.

Comment: is there any other solution other than getting the pixel?

Comment: and what if there is another green pixel other than what you declared?

Comment: @AJB you mean a different shade of green? In that case you can just check if the pixel is not white (or transparent, depending on what you have).

Comment: what i mean is that what if you paint objectA as green but there is already an object that is color green also

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick demo. Move your mouse within 5px of either end of the line to see the guides.

The idea is that it uses collision detection to work out if the mouse is within 5 pixels of the start or end of the line.

You can easily change from ugly square guides to a circle. You can essentially do what you want.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 400;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

//add as many lines as you want
var lines = [
  {start: {x: 100, y: 100}, end: {x: 200, y: 300}},
  {start: {x: 200, y: 150}, end: {x: 50, y: 250}},
  {start: {x: 240, y: 240}, end: {x: 450, y: 150}},
  {start: {x: 160, y: 340}, end: {x: 10, y: 90}},
  {start: {x: 380, y: 270}, end: {x: 300, y: 380}}
];

function render(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,400);
  for(var c = 0; c < lines.length; c++){
    ctx.moveTo(lines[c].start.x, lines[c].start.y);
    ctx.lineTo(lines[c].end.x, lines[c].end.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

render();

var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  mouse.x = e.clientX;
  mouse.y = e.clientY;
  render();
  for(var c = 0; c < lines.length; c++){
    if(
      //check if within 10px of start of line
      (mouse.x > lines[c].start.x - 5 &&
       mouse.x < lines[c].start.x + 5 &&
       mouse.y > lines[c].start.y - 5 &&
       mouse.y < lines[c].start.y + 5) ||
      //same for the end of the line
      (mouse.x > lines[c].end.x - 5 &&
       mouse.x < lines[c].end.x + 5 &&
       mouse.y > lines[c].end.y - 5 &&
       mouse.y < lines[c].end.y + 5)
    ){
      showGuides(c);
    }
  }
});
//function to show the guides
function showGuides(i){
  ctx.fillRect(lines[i].start.x - 5, lines[i].start.y - 5, 10, 10);
  ctx.fillRect(lines[i].end.x - 5, lines[i].end.y - 5, 10, 10);
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

^ ^ ^

|  |  |

Run code snippet

Comment: Its a good example but you dont want to hard-code every lines

Comment: @AJB Just create an array of all of your lines and loop through it. If you want I can change it that way.

Comment: @AJB Just changed to iterate through an array.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that you do use a Path for drawing the lines, while op uses fillRect(). So, **you** could even simply call the [ctx.isPointInPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) method, but that won't work with OP's [actual code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10130705/3702797).

Comment: @Kaiido I'm not making his image editor for him, I'm simply showing him the best way to go about doing what he's asked. I know the way he did it is different to how I did, but that was just because the question is only relevant to one aspect of his editor. The whole point is he can copy or recreate the important part of my demo. I just used a path for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Ps and not directly related :  don't forget to add or substract the canvas's offset to your mouse coordinates or it will break (like here when we scroll down in the snippet's iframe)

Comment: @Kaiido It's meant to be viewed full screen, not squashed into a space where you need to scroll around.