# How to reset transparency when drawing overlapping content on HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm drawing with a semi-transparent color (e.g. `rgba(255,0,0,0.5)`) over a canvas. When I draw over the same region again, the transparency value seems to be adding up resulting in an opaque color. Is there a way to keep the transparency value of the source (the semi-transparent color I'm using to draw) instead?

Comment: @Kaiido. Nope, **this is a much more interesting question** than a `clearRect` problem! ;-) They want to draw a semi-transparent fill and then partly overlay another semi-transparent fill -- but the overlapping area should have only the second fill (not a mix of the 2 alpha fills). After short thoughts, I can't think of a compositing solution because compositing respects alphas. It might come down to a `.getImageData` solution.

Comment: @markE but it seems counter-intuitive to me : if I draw multiple times with a semi-transparent color, it seems normal that it becomes more and more opaque. If OP wants always the same alpha, maybe `globalAlpha` property can be considered, or `clearRect()` only on the will-be redrawn pixels. But it's not clear what should `rgba(0,255,0,0.5)` + `rgba(0,0,255,0.5)` should return. `rgba(0, 107, 147, 0.5)` as if it were `.25` for both alpha colors ?

Comment: Yes, it's counter-intuitive -- normally you want additive alphas so you simulate something like combined water colors. I'm (totally) guessing they are adding semi-transparent annotations to some image underneath and they want the second semi-transparent color to completely overwrite the first semi-transparent color. If they are just using alpha to get a certain color, they could convert `rgba --> rgb` to get fully opaque colors and then use compositing to get their effect.

Comment: Chuckling at myself! :-)) In my last comment if all the colors are converted to opaque, then you don't need compositing, you just draw sequentially and the next color always overwrites the last color.

Comment: **szimek...We need a bit more info from you.** Do you need semi-transparency (if no, convert rgba to rgb)? Are all your alpha values the same (if yes, Blindman67 has your solution)?

Comment: @markE I'm the author of http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad library. It draws curves with variable width using circles, because there's no native way to do it. If you use a semi-transparent color (e.g. open the demo page and type `signaturePad.penColor = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"` in the console) and draw some lines, you'll notice small circles along the line - it's where the circles are overlapping. That's the first issue - if I could make transparency non additive, I could easily fix it. Also, if it worked, it could be used to highlight anything already drawn on the canvas (e.g. image).

Comment: @szimek Then use Blindman67 solution : perform your drawings on an opaque offscreen canvas, and simultaneously draw it on the main one after you drawn a saved state and after you set its globalAlpha to the one wanted. on mouseup, save this main canvas on a second off-screen canvas and clear the shape one  : http://jsfiddle.net/ng8hjzLo/ ps : jsfiddle base code comes from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005977/how-to-detect-if-mouse-position-is-hovering/33006913#33006913) and so from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122553/)

Comment: I'm late to the party, but you can draw the new content twice--first with a `globalCompositeOperation` of `destination-out`, second with `source-over`. The solution is described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39238489

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw to an offscreen canvas with `alpha = 1`.Then just render the off screen canvas to the display canvas with the `ctx.globalAlpha` set at whatever value you wish. That way you can draw till the sun goes down without adding anything to the alpha. It is also easy to change the alpha after you have drawn if needed.

**Additional note**

If you have other content included in the image, you will have to keep that on another layer as well because this method relies on the onscreen canvas being reset to a desired starting state for each update. In the snippet this is just a `clearRect` call. But can just as well be replaced with another existing layer, or a combination there of.

The browser can easily handle many off screen canvases, I just finished a job that had 60 full screen canvas stacked on top of each other (Note your GPU needs to have the RAM to hold the images or it's too slow) and Chrome did not even blink. Firefox and IE are just as capable.

**UPDATE**

I have added a snippet to demonstrate what I mean. Details in the comments of the relevant code at the bottom. Just a simple drawing interface.

```js
// get canvas set up mouse and do the other things
var canvas = document.getElementById("canV"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var mouse = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    buttonLastRaw:0, // user modified value 
    buttonRaw:0,
    over:false,
};
function mouseMove(event){
    mouse.x = event.offsetX;  mouse.y = event.offsetY; 
    if(mouse.x === undefined){ mouse.x = event.clientX;  mouse.y = event.clientY;}    
    if(event.type === "mousedown"){ mouse.buttonRaw = 1;
    }else if(event.type === "mouseup"){mouse.buttonRaw = 0;
    }else if(event.type === "mouseout"){ mouse.buttonRaw = 0; mouse.over = false;
    }else if(event.type === "mouseover"){ mouse.over = true; }
    event.preventDefault();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',mouseMove);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',mouseMove);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup'  ,mouseMove); 
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout'  ,mouseMove); 
canvas.addEventListener('mouseover'  ,mouseMove); 
canvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){      canvas.preventDefault();}, false);

// create off screen layer that we will draw to
var layer1 = document.createElement("canvas");  
layer1.width = w;   // same size as the onscreen canvas
layer1.height = h; 
layer1.ctx = layer1.getContext("2d"); 
// set up drawing settings
layer1.ctx.lineCap = "round";
layer1.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
layer1.ctx.lineWidth = 16;
layer1.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;  // draw to this layer with alpha set to 1;

// set up onscreen canvas
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.font = "24px Arial black";
var instructions = true;

// colours to show that different layer are overwriting each other
var colours = "#F00,#FF0,#0F0,#0FF,#00F,#F0F".split(",");
var currentCol = 0;

// update on animation frame
function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);  // clear onscreen
    var c = layer1.ctx;      // short cut to the later1 context
    if(mouse.buttonRaw){    // if mouse down 
        if(mouse.lastx === undefined){   // is this start of drawing stroke
            mouse.lastx = mouse.x;   // set up drawing stroke
            mouse.lasty = mouse.y;
         c.strokeStyle = colours[currentCol % colours.length];
            currentCol += 1;
            instructions = false;   // tuen of the instructions as they have worked it out
            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;  // should do this near layering but lasy
        }
        // draw the dragged stroke to the offscreen layer
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(mouse.lastx,mouse.lasty);
        c.lineTo(mouse.x,mouse.y);
        c.stroke();
        mouse.lastx = mouse.x;
        mouse.lasty = mouse.y;        
    }else{  // if the mouse button up show drawing brush and instructions if
            // nothing has happened yet
        mouse.lastx = undefined;    // using this as a semaphore for drag start
        ctx.fillStyle = colours[currentCol%colours.length];
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;    // the brush will compound the alpha 
                                   // this can be avoided by drawing it onto
                                   // the offscreen layer, but you will need 
                                   // another layer or some temp store to 
                                   // protect the offscreen layer. Again I am
                                   // to lazy to implement that right now.
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(mouse.x,mouse.y,8,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();
        if(instructions){         // show instructions if needed
          ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
          ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
          ctx.fillText("Click drag mouse to draw",250,60);
        }
    }
    
    // draw the offscreen layer onto the onscreen canvas at the alpha wanted
    ctx.drawImage(layer1,0,0);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);  // do it all again.
}
mouse.lastx;  // needed to draw lines.
mouse.lasty;
update()
```

```css
body {    background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAlUlEQVRYR+2WsQ0EIQwEbXpAopbrAZESUhQ1AAkBXVEDAb6jBRP8B0s+yJpklnvvstYizRMRyjmTtVaD096buNYqzjnVB3NOaq3RGEPFhxBwAAzAAAzAAAz8gYFSijCzqmYH+ngyxqj4k3N+nkduep5Sops9wV+T5abnMUa62RM4AAZgAAZgAAZ+b8B7Lzc9PzW82RMvg0g+JLdy9xIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');


    background-size: 32px 32px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
.canC { width:500px;  height:600px;}
```

```html
<canvas class="canC" id="canV" width=500 height=600></canvas>
```

Comment: Sounds promising...but only if all the alphas are the same.

Comment: 60 simultaneous full screen renderings -- wow! Just curious...what was the app that required that many overlays?

Comment: A very deep (layers) parallax image view of some microscope images.

Comment: Cool! Sounds like an interesting project -- and interesting projects keep us from thinking of programming as a chore.

Comment: @Kaiido Will add a snippet to clarify.

Comment: So the solution is to use `clearRect` on the on-screen canvas isn't it? "That way you can draw till the sun goes down without adding anything to the alpha." still sounds wrong to me with the rest of your text

Comment: Yes, clear it or use a background image. I seldom use the onscreen canvas for anything but a viewport. All rendering and content is in back buffers. The view port is a transient multi dimensional transformable surface.  Anyways I will re read what I wrote to see if I have been too unclear.