# Overwrite drawn over canvas when drawing transparent shapes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transparency

I can't see that this had been posted already, so here goes.

Let's say i draw 2 squares on the canvas.

```
var c = document.getElementById('test'), ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(25, 0);
ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx.lineTo(0, 50);
ctx.lineTo(25, 0);
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 0);
ctx.lineTo(75, 50);
ctx.lineTo(25, 50);
ctx.lineTo(50, 0);
ctx.fill();
```

This produces this image:

[image]

If i change globalAlpha to 0.5, i get this:

[image]

However, i want to produce this:

[image]

As in, all pixels are transparent and any images under it will appear, but the pixels created by the red triangle will overwrite the existing blue triangle where it is drawn.

And ctx.globalComposisteOperation doesn't seem to help in this instance due to it also factoring the transparency and the fact i want to keep both squares.

Is there any way to do this with current methods?

Comment: I'm not understanding. How is the end result transparent? Did you want a white transparent overlay? Looks like you could get the achieved end result by simply changing the colors, then you wouldn't even need to use an alpha.

Comment: @Dom It's possible they're rendering to a second canvas to create an transparent overlay. Sort of like a UI layer. But I have no idea if that's what OP is actually doing.

Comment: @MikeC very true, given the example provided, it's very hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

Use Compositing to clear the red triangle before drawing it.

Using compositing is slightly better than clipping because you don't have to clear the clip. Clearing a clip requires saving the entire context state and then restoring that context state -- many properties involved. Compositing just requires changing 1 property forth and back.

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// fill the blue rect
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(25, 0);
ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx.lineTo(0, 50);
ctx.lineTo(25, 0);
ctx.fill();

// define the red rect path
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 0);
ctx.lineTo(75, 50);
ctx.lineTo(25, 50);
ctx.lineTo(50, 0);

// clear the red rect path using compositing
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';
ctx.fillStyle='black';
ctx.fill();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';

// fill the red rect
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
ctx.fill();
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Layers

Do it the photoshop way and create layers to do the work for you. Creating a layer (second canvas) is no more trouble than loading an image. You can create dozens and have no problem and it makes this type of work easy.

First create a second canvas (layer)

```
// canvas is original canvas 
var layer = document.createElement("canvas");
layer.width = canvas.width;  // same size as original 
layer.height = canvas.height;
var ctx1 = layer.getContext("2d");
```

Then draw your triangles on the second canvas with alpha = 1;

```
var tri = (x,c)=>{
    ctx1.fillStyle = c;
    ctx1.beginPath();
    ctx1.moveTo(25 + x, 0);
    ctx1.lineTo(50 + x, 50);
    ctx1.lineTo(0 + x, 50);
    ctx1.closePath();
    ctx1.fill();
}
tri(0,"#00f");
tri(25,"#f00");
```

Then just draw that layer on top of the canvas you are working on with the alpha value you want.

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
ctx.drawImage(layer,0,0);
```

If you don't need the extra layer delete the canvas and context by dereferencing them.

```
ctx1 = undefined;
layer = undefined;
```

Or you can keep the layer , and make another layer for the background and mix them in real time to get the FX  just right

```js
    //
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var layer = document.createElement("canvas");
    layer.width = canvas.width;  // same size as original 
    layer.height = canvas.height;
    var ctx1 = layer.getContext("2d");
    var tri = (x,c)=>{
        ctx1.fillStyle = c;
        ctx1.beginPath();
        ctx1.moveTo(25 + x, 0);
        ctx1.lineTo(50 + x, 50);
        ctx1.lineTo(0 + x, 50);
        ctx1.fill();
    }
    tri(0,"#00f");
    tri(25,"#0f0");
    tri(50,"#f00");
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.drawImage(layer,0,0);
    layer = ctx1 = undefined;
```

Comment: You can save two lines by calling `layer = canvas.cloneNode()`. Also, I guessed OP was already playing with layers (I think he said he would draw it on other shapes), but to create one more layer for just this may be cumbersome at some point, so gCO is a good fit to update a single layer.

Comment: @Kaiido  gCO becomes an pain when you are overwriting existing content, which I get the idea that the OP was wanting, and there could be a situation where you want to `"screen"`  or `"color-burn"`...  the result.

Comment: I meant use gCO to update each layer, then draw it on the main as you wish. Anyway, I guess OP has enough solutions now, each with there pros and cons and all depending on needs we don't know enough to be good judges ;-)

Comment: This trick becomes complicated if the two shapes have different alpha values.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the area for the second rectangle before drawing it.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('game'), 
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

// Clear the extra bit of the blue rectangle
ctx.clearRect(25, 25, 25, 25);

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 50, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Comment: Sorry, should have made my issue more clear. I edited my example after seeing this to better reflect what i'm actually trying to do...

Comment: @Iblob I see you changed it to triangles with your last edit. The same principle still applies. Clear out the area which is going to be drawn into first. If you don't actually require transparency then go with Dom's answer. If you need to draw these over existing graphics without destroying them then you need to specify that.

Comment: Thanks! I found out about ctx.clip() that limits drawing to the current path, then i can simply just clear the clipped area and draw the shape.

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly suggest just changing the colors and avoid using an alpha.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('game'), 
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "#8080FF";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff8080";
ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 50, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = document.getElementById('test'), ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(25, 0);
ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx.lineTo(0, 50);
ctx.lineTo(25, 0);
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 0);
ctx.lineTo(75, 50);
ctx.lineTo(25, 50);
ctx.lineTo(50, 0);
ctx.clip();
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
```

Just use clip() to take the current path, clear everything in there with clearRect, then draw the path as normal.

Answer (score 0):

@markE is right, use compositing instead of clipping (really heavy).

However, his solution will only work if you've drawn everything with an rgba color. Maybe I read your question wrongly, but if you're going from an opaque shape and want to make it transparent, then you should rather use the `copy` gCO and the `globalAlpha` property.

This will have less performance impact since `drawImage` is faster than `fill`, and will allow you to perform a fade-out effect ; but it really depends on your needs.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
// initial blue
ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(25, 0);
ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx.lineTo(0, 50);
ctx.lineTo(25, 0);
ctx.fill();

setTimeout(function drawRed() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(50, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(75, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(25, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(50, 0);
  ctx.fill();
}, 500);

btn.onclick = function makeItTransparent() {
  // if we weere to make this into an animation, we would set it only once
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
  ctx.globalAlpha = .8;
  // draw the canvas on itself
  ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0);
  // once again, in an animation we won't reset this to default
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
};
```

```css
/* checkboard background */
canvas {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAGElEQVQYlWNgYGBowIKxgqGgcJA5h3yFAOI3GQFqqi5ZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<button id="btn">make it transparent</button>
```